# How to get lat and lng from a Geolocation

Tags: php, google-maps

The following sample code provided by google maps api

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 10
  });



     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
     });


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      marker.setPosition(pos);
      /*infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');*/
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {

    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'position_changed',function(){
            var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

            $('#lat').val(lat);
            $('#lng').val(lng);
     });



function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
</script>
```

the following only shows google map of the location and a marker. I was wondering how can I get the latitude/longitude parameters and get the location name?

Thanks in advance! any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). The conversion of latitude & longitude to a location name is called Reverse Geocoding.